# What is the difference between the traditional Mongo index method and the new text index?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Bear with me, I'm not anywhere near advanced with MongoDB. What is the difference between these two index statements:

```
db.things.createIndex({ name: 1 });
db.things.createIndex({ name: "text" });
```

Is it a rule to always use text indexes with text fields? What is the difference between the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Text indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) are good for matching on content that is contained in a field, while a standard index is good for matching specific values of a field.  For example, a text index would be good if you wanted to match `California` in the following field:

```
{
  ...
  description: 'I like to visit California in the Fall'
  ...
}
```

While a standard index would be good for matching:

```
{
  ...
  state: 'California'
  ...
}
```

Keep in mind that text indexes are much larger than standard indexes so only use them when you really need them.